# GSON issue with String

Tags: java, gson, linkedhashmap

```
    String s = "m\\"+"/m\\/m/m/m/m/m";

    LinkedHashMap<String, String> hm = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    hm.put("test", s);

    System.out.println(hm+"  Hash map = "+hm.toString());
```

Fine Output is `{test=m\/m\/m/m/m/m/m}  Hash map = {test=m\/m\/m/m/m/m/m}`

```
    String s2 = new Gson().toJson(hm.toString());

    System.out.println("Json result is "+s2);
```

**Not Fine** Output is `Json result is "{test\u003dm\\/m\\/m/m/m/m/m}"`

Is **GSON** going mad or is it something that I am doing wrong? What is happening to with **Back Slashes** and from where does this `u003d` appears? I knew that there exists a bug of this nature a long time ago but it was resolved. 
How can I resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: its encoding again: `=` to `\u003dm` and `\ to `\\\`

Comment: How can I solve the later issue. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The `=` sign is encoded to `\u003d.` Hence you need to use [disableHtmlEscaping()](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.7/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#disableHtmlEscaping--).

You can use

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
String s2 = gson.toJson(hm.toString());
```

For `\/` turning into `\\/` issue, the solution is

```
s2.replace("\\\\", "\\");
```

Comment: what about \n ?? Because \n also added sometimes in string.

Comment: @Bajarang Use like this String base64EncodedData = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP);

Comment: Thanks. This helps me.

Answer (score 3):

Since some people like to nitpick, I'll add the answer to the question (even though it was already answered and chosen as the correct answer) ...

I agree with the chose answer to this question, use the following code:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
String s2 = gson.toJson(hm.toString());
s2.replace("\\\\", "\\");
```

@Bajrang Hudda has asked about \n ... I hit this issue recently ... I was able to solve it using:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = (gson.toJson(data)).replaceAll("\\\\n", "\\n");
```

Comment: But this is not an answer to the original question, as far as I can see.

Comment: @anothernode I couldn't add a response to that guy under the question when lower than 50 rep points... So I added another response here, sue me.

Comment: Look, I was just giving you a friendly hint. No need to be offended. And copying and pasting someone else's answer into your non-answer doesn't make the situation much better.